# Make Toolbar Transparent when Scrolled Up and Make it Visible when Scrolled Down

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I just want to make the **android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar** transparent when we scroll down the **RecyclerView** and make clearly visible when we scroll up

This is my Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ae43ff"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/unnamed"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        />

    <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->

    <!--app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"-->
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#6fffc6">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And the Output I am Getting

[image]

I tried many different ways, but its not working as I want.

I dont want the effect which we get in **android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout**

I want the effect as shown in this [Video](https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/rezXzeTxwRdGxvi9fLJUOw4VKccxjNue/2015_09_14_23_37_58.mp4)

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing similar problem, which I have cracked in this way.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="206dip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:titleEnabled="false">




        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSomeTextDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text Display1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSomeOtherText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text Display 2"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        </LinearLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>       
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

And in the Activity class, OnCreate what I did was -

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {


        int intColorCode=0;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {


           intColorCode=-(verticalOffset);
            if(intColorCode>255)
                intColorCode=255;

            toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(intColorCode);
            toolbar.setAlpha(intColorCode);


        }
    });
```

I managed to get the desired effect for one of my projects. Let me know if you need any more assistance. Since I am still perfecting the code, the code can be made better, if anyone has suggestions, feel free to put in your comments.

Comment: It's almost perfect, thanks. Except that `setAlpha` method gets a float. So you should change your code to `*.setAlpha(intColorCode/256f)`

Comment: i have used your code, but it is not as transparent background. I wants like snapchat is doing in discover screen

Comment: Note that there is a bug in SDK and when you change alpha of background from code you also change alpha of all views that use that color as background. So I would recomment use ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, alpha). It will generate new color with alpha every time, but we avoid the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with setting layout_behavior to your `Toolbar`. Wrote an article that could help you understand how it works and how you can utilize the power of `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`. Also here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/e587669f3d9b1519bc5e).

Basically, it computes the ratio between the total scroll range of the `AppBarLayout` and current `AppBarLayout` bottom. The ratio is used to set alpha to `Toolbar` background.

https://medium.com/@nullthemall/1-20f-behaviors-of-alpha-6f506c9cb6a7